# Set view to match_parent in a layout in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, view, infowindow

I have a tiny problem with a InfoWindow layout.
I am trying to set a view in the layout to match the parent in width, but I get some small gaps in the left and right margins.
I tried with LinearLayout, RelativeLayout and ConstraintLayout as root view, I get the same results.

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                         android:layout_margin="0dp"
                                         android:orientation="vertical"
                                         android:padding="0dp">

<View
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:background="@color/login_button_color"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

</View>

<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/profile_image_info_view"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:src="@drawable/com_facebook_profile_picture_blank_portrait"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    tools:ignore="InefficientWeight"
    android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="80dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/owner_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/placeholder"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/profile_image_info_view"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.17000002"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/event_title_info_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:foregroundGravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/placeholder"
    android:textColor="@color/com_facebook_button_background_color"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/owner_name"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.92"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And a screenshot:

[image]

This is how I inflate it:

```
mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker)
                        {
                            return null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker)
                        {
                            View view = 
                    getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_info_view, 
                    null);
                            profileImageInfoView = (CircleImageView) 
                    view.findViewById(R.id.profile_image_info_view);
                            ownerName = 
                    (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.owner_name);
                            eventTitle = (TextView) 
                    view.findViewById(R.id.event_title_info_view);
                            return view;
                        }
                    });
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please post the code of info window.

Comment: I just set it up with a layoutInflater and made it open with an onMarkerClick, I didn't do anything with it yet.

Comment: Why is your width 0 in the View?

Comment: it is a constraint layout as root view, it puts it that way when I set the constraints

Comment: Problem is you ddnt set the constraints properly there is only left constraint, you should add right constraint too. And why is your parent having wrap_content dimens?

Comment: I set it now to the right constraint too and put the constraint as match_parent width and height, same thing

Comment: for what you use this layout? dialog? Toolbar? others?

Comment: Is your parent layout having any margins? You told you are inflating this view on top of other view right, did you check the margins there?

Comment: I hope you already tried relativelayout instead of constraint layout and setting width = "match_parent" for both relativelayout & view.

Comment: yup, and the same with LinearLayout

Comment: @MohammedAtif the mapLayout is inflated programatically,it is just a default MapFragment

Comment: If your problem is not solved then can you please post the code of info window. I want to check it.

Comment: @AvijitKarmakar I posted the way I inflate it with a InfoWindowAdapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have written in `getInfoContents()` method move it to the `getInfoWindow()` method.

If you use `getInfoContents()` method then it will add a white background with some padding but `getInfoWindow()` method does not do that.

Updated code will be:

```
mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_info_view, null);
        profileImageInfoView = (CircleImageView) 
        view.findViewById(R.id.profile_image_info_view);
        ownerName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.owner_name);
        eventTitle = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.event_title_info_view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
        return null;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"    
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"       
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </View>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**EDIT:**

Change this in dimens.xml

```
<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">0dp</dimen>

<dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">0dp</dimen>
```

Comment: didn't change anyhitng sadly

Comment: I believe it works as a fragment, but I use it as a InfoWindow in my MapFragment, I get the same result

Comment: I updated the question with the way I inflate it, the MapFragment is opened programatically and inflated from a default MapFragment, I don't have a layout for it

Comment: Change the following in dimens.xml `<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">0dp</dimen>`
`<dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">0dp</dimen>`

Answer (score 0):

make your ConstraintLayout's width match parent. maybe your ConstraintLayout taking width size from its child.

Comment: same result, and if I change view width to match_parent the InfoWindow just stretches to the map width, but I still have the gaps

Comment: change view child with a linearlayout and make width match parent also.